# Python pandas - group, count, plot multi-series

Tags: python, pandas

I have the below dataset from a survey that give each participant a list of foods and asks them to rank how likely they are to eat them this week. I want to plot the count for each likelhood of each food type on a graph.

```
Person    Food     Label
John      Pizza    Likely
John      Chinese  Unlikely
John      French   Very Unlikely
Debbie    Pizza    Unlikely
Debbie    Chinese  Very Likely
Debbie    French   Very Unlikely
```

For example:

```
Pizza     Likely         1
Pizza     Unlikely       1
Chinese   Unlikely       1
Chinese   Very Unlikely  1
French    Very Unlikely  2
```

So far I have read my file into a dataframe and done some basic cleaning.

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data = pd.read_excel('my_file_path')

#cleaning code
clean_data = raw_data(clean)

results = clean_data.groupby(['Food', 'Label']).count()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need to add column `Person` after `groupby`, reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) and plot by [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
results = clean_data.groupby(['Food', 'Label'])['Person'].count().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Another solution with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
results = pd.crosstab(clean_data['Food'], clean_data['Label'])

print (results)
Label    Likely  Unlikely  Very Likely  Very Unlikely
Food                                                 
Chinese       0         1            1              0
French        0         0            0              2
Pizza         1         1            0              0

results.plot.bar()
```

[image: plot]

Comment: when I unstack, I can no longer access rows and columns by their label. i.e. results['Food'] or results['Label']